# Exporting Jest test results to txt

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I can report my test results by using 'reporters' method of jest configuration but it shows all the reports on the console. I want something that it creates files like .txt

Is it possible to do ?

Here's my jest configuration;

```
"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^.+\\.css$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "verbose": true,
    "bail": true,
    "reporters": [
      "default",
      "<rootDir>/__test__/my-custom-reporter.js"
    ]
  }
```

And my-custom-reporters.js ;

```
class MyCustomReporter {
  constructor(globalConfig, options) {
    this._globalConfig = globalConfig;
    this._options = options;
  }

  onRunComplete(contexts, results) {
    console.log('Custom reporter output:');
    console.log('GlobalConfig: ', contexts);
    console.log('Options: ', results);
  }

  onTestResult(test, testResult, aggregatedResult) {
    console.log('onTestResult:');
    console.log('test: ', test);
    console.log('testResult: ', testResult);
    console.log('aggregatedResult: ', aggregatedResult);
  }

  onRunStart(results, options) {
    console.log('onRunStart:');
    console.log('results: ', results);
    console.log('Options: ', options);
  }

  onTestStart(test) {
    console.log('onTestStart:');
    console.log('test: ', test);
  }

  getLastError() {
    if (this._shouldFail) {
      return new Error('my-custom-reporter.js reported an error');
    }
  }
}

module.exports = MyCustomReporter;
```

Comment: You can append to a buffer instead / on top of calling `console.log`, then write the buffer to a file. Or run the test and redirect the console output to a file, e.g. `npm test > testlog.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a perfect way to report results in a file.

I used "**write-file-p**" module to write the results in a json file.

So my class turned into like this;

```
const writeFileP = require("write-file-p");

class MyCustomReporter {
  constructor(globalConfig, options) {
    this._globalConfig = globalConfig;
    this._options = options;
  }

  onRunComplete(contexts, results) {
    console.log('onRunComplete:');
    // Write a json syncronously
    writeFileP.sync(`${__dirname}/testResults/onRunComplete.json`, JSON.stringify(contexts)+"\n\n\n"+JSON.stringify(results));
  }

  onTestResult(test, testResult, aggregatedResult) {
    console.log('onTestResult:');
    // Write a json syncronously
    writeFileP.sync(`${__dirname}/testResults/onTestResult.json`, JSON.stringify(test)+"\n\n\n"+JSON.stringify(testResult)+"\n\n\n"+JSON.stringify(aggregatedResult));
  }

  onRunStart(results, options) {
    console.log('onRunStart:');
    // Write a json syncronously
    writeFileP.sync(`${__dirname}/testResults/onRunStart.json`, JSON.stringify(results)+"\n\n\n"+JSON.stringify(options));
  }

  onTestStart(test) {
    console.log('onTestStart:');
    // Write a json syncronously
    writeFileP.sync(`${__dirname}/testResults/onTestStart.json`, JSON.stringify(test));
  }

  getLastError() {
    if (this._shouldFail) {
      return new Error('my-custom-reporter.js reported an error');
    }
  }
}

module.exports = MyCustomReporter;
```

So all of the reports are written into those **json** files.